# how to set freepbx call recordings to mp3 stereo?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mp3, asterisk, audio-recording, freepbx

how to set freepbx calls to mp3 stereo? Currently, the recordings in mixmonitor WAV. Please help

-freepbx 12.0.76
-ubuntu 14
-asterisk 11

Comment: Can you spend a few more minutes on this post? It would be helpful to know exactly what you've tried and what you need help with.

Comment: If you use Monitor (instead of MixMonitor) you can get both audio channels separately and run a script easily to mix them however you'd like, including to mp3. This link will help you on your way: http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/applikationen-monitor.html

Comment: Sorry for my post.. my freepbx generate a Mixmonitor recordings. how can i set it to Monitor? and mix them afterwards w/o deleting the both audio channels generate by monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Note, I use Centos. The following may need to be adjusted for your OS.

I use the following script to convert the MixMonitor output to MP3.
You need to install lame on your machine to use this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
wavfile=/path/to/RecordedWavFiles/$1 
lame -b 192 -m m $wavfile ${wavfile%.*}.mp3
rm -f $1
```

Note that the script deletes the wav file, so maybe remove that line until you are sure it's working properly.

Save it somewhere as converttomp3.sh and set the permissions accordingly with `chmod` so it can be executed.

In FreePBX, go to Settings> Advanced Settings.

Change `Display Readonly Settings` to True and save.

Change `Override Readonly Settings` to True and save.

Refresh the page.

Now you'll find a setting called `Post Call Recording Script`

Put in the full path to the converttomp3.sh script along with ^${CALLFILENAME}

eg. `/usr/bin/converttomp3.sh ^${CALLFILENAME}`

I'm not sure you need the ^ character, but that's what the documentation recommends. If it doesn't work, try removing it.

Save and update, and then give it a go.

Comment: awesome, do you have the script for splitting both lines(L&R)?

Comment: Sorry, I only use MixMonitor. If you want to have separate recording for L+R, you need to use Monitor but I'm not sure how you would then mix the recordings together.

Comment: do you know how to activate the Monitor and not the Mixmonitor? im using  the freepbx 12 with asterisk 11

Comment: Look for the setting called `Use MixMonitor for Recordings`

Comment: yes i already set it to false but still the recordings is mix to 1 recording

Comment: Looking at the tooltip for that setting, when you set to false, it should not mix. Did you update also?

Comment: It looks like someone already asked your question on the FreePBX forum but got no answer. Maybe the `Use MixMonitor` option is not working as the poster seems to say that MixMonitor is still used when that option is changed to False. http://community.freepbx.org/t/trouble-configuring-freepbx-for-stereo-recordings/19714

Comment: If that is the case, you'll need to override the existing dialplan yourself. If you want to write your own dialplan, you put it in extensions_override_freepbx.conf.

Comment: ahmm im not that knowledgeable enough for script or dialplan thing, like i said im newbie to this.

Comment: Looking at the current situation, you won't be able to achieve this by using the FreePBX GUI. You'll either need to learn Asterisk dialplans, or pay someone to assist you. Sorry, but that seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You need create script which convert wav to mp3(or hire someone).

After that put that script in mixmonitor script field in general options(freepbx options in some versions) tab.

Comment: Sorry for my post.. my freepbx generate a Mixmonitor recordings. how can i set it to Monitor? and mix them afterwards w/o deleting the both audio channels generate by monitor?

Comment: sorry im newbie not sure when to activate this or deactivate

Comment: ill deal the mp3 later

Comment: hi, thanks for the screenshot. im using freepbx 12 and im not sure where to find it

Comment: i found it and activate it. Now, im not sure what to put,can you help with this one please?

Comment: You need create bash script which will convert your wav to mp3. Or hire someone on freelancer.com or upwork.com to do that work for you. That task require midle level linux skill

Comment: except for mp3, how can i activate the stereo and monitor? My freepbx generate Mono.

Comment: It may give you 2 files at moment when that script executed. Anyway, some debugging and experimenting required and it WILL depend of asterisk version.

Comment: "It may give you 2 files at moment when that script executed." - How? sorry newbie here

Comment: Before version 1.8 it was one file filename-in.wav, one filename-out.wav. At version 11 - seams like only via special options, but that have be tested.

Comment: what special options? how and where can i set it in freepbx?

Comment: There are no easy way do it in freepbx. Need write special module(3-5hrs for expert) or ovveride dialplan.